# Python, XP to Level converter

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so im bassicly trying to convert a players XP into a level number, im just wondering if there is a more efficant way / neater way as this looks horrible and compared to something looks like it takes time as it had to run every elif. Cheers.

```
# XP to Level converter
    if self.xp >= "0":
        self.level = "Level 0"
    elif self.xp >= "1000":
        self.level = "Level 1"
    elif self.xp >= "3000":
        self.level = "Level 2"
    elif self.xp >= "5000":
        self.level = "Level 3"
    elif self.xp >= "7500":
        self.level = "Level 4"
    elif self.xp >= "10000":
        self.level = "Level 5"
    elif self.xp >= "13000":
        self.level = "Level 6"
    elif self.xp >= "15000":
        self.level = "Level 7"
    elif self.xp >= "20000":
        self.level = "Level 8"
    elif self.xp >= "25000":
        self.level = "Level 9"
    elif self.xp >= "30000":
        self.level = "Level 10"
    elif self.xp >= "35000":
        self.level = "Level 11"
    elif self.xp >= "41000":
        self.level = "Level 12"
    elif self.xp >= "47500":
        self.level = "Level 13"
    elif self.xp >= "52500":
        self.level = "Level 14"
    elif self.xp >= "60000":
        self.level = "Level 15"
    elif self.xp >= "68000":
        self.level = "Level 16"
    elif self.xp >= "76500":
        self.level = "Level 17"
    elif self.xp >= "85500":
        self.level = "Level 18"
    elif self.xp >= "95000":
        self.level = "Level 19"
    elif self.xp >= "105000":
        self.level = "Level 20"
    elif self.xp >= "115000":
        self.level = "MAX LEVEL"
    else:
        self.level = "Level Could Not Be Converted"

    print(self.level)
```

Comment: You can create dict with xp as key and level as value and then just comparing.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yeah, you can use `prev = 0; for key, value in lvl_dict.items(): if xp < key and xp >= prev: print(value); prev = key`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use arrays for the levelpoints

```
xp = 7600

limit = [0,1000,3000,5000,7500,10000]
level = -1

for points in limit:
    if xp > points:
        level = level + 1
    else:
        break

print(level)
```

Comment: Works more of less great !, had a bit of fiddling to do but this worked great, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to make levels happen in regular increments (e.g. consistently every 5000 xp), you could use something simple and fast:

```
# Defined at the top, easily modifiable this way
max_level = 21
xp_per_level = 5000

...

level_number = self.xp // xp_per_level
self.level = f"Level {level_number}" if level_number < max_level else "MAX LEVEL"
```

You can nest the above behavior in an elif similar to how you have already, and use this technique to have the first 10 levels scale by 500 xp per level, and maybe the next 10 require 1000 xp, etc.